# How can I change [kafka-consumer-1] this thread name?

Tags: spring-kafka

I set the concurrency to 10 and I can see 10 different thread id but the thread name is all the same. How can set the listener name? I tried container.setBeanName but no luck. Please help. By the way I am use 1.1.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread names are unique; it's just that boot's logging configuration truncates the name by default; we will [fix the default thread naming](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/265) but, in the meantime, you can either change the logging configuration or use named executors. Use `setConsumerTaskExecutor(execC())` and `setListenerTaskExecutor(execL())` on the container's `ContainerProperties` ...

```
@Bean
public AsyncListenableTaskExecutor execC() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor tpte = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    tpte.setCorePoolSize(15);
    return tpte;
}

@Bean
public AsyncListenableTaskExecutor execL() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor tpte = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    tpte.setCorePoolSize(15);
    return tpte;
}
```